# Simplfiying a system output equation

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, homework

I have a problem getting the final (simplified) version of the system's (in the figure below) output equation y[n]:
[image]

For this system, I know that $$w[n] = x[n] + aw[n − 1]$$ and $$y[n] = w[n] + bw[n − 1] = x[n] + aw[n − 1] + bw[n − 1] $$ however, the simplification method that yields this form: $$y[n] = x[n] + bx[n − 1] + ay[n − 1]$$ is not clear for me. Could anyone give me any tips/methods for deriving the final form of y[n]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These problems are most easily solved by using the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform. But it is also possible to do it in the sample domain. You have two equations for expressing $w[n]$ and $w[n-1]$ in terms of $x[n]$ and $y[n]$:

$$x[n]=w[n]-aw[n-1]\tag{1}$$
$$y[n]=w[n]+bw[n-1]\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, $w[n]$ is obtained as

$$w[n]=\frac{1}{a+b}\big(bx[n]+ay[n]\big)\tag{3}$$

Plugging $(3)$ into $(2)$ gives

$$y[n]=\frac{1}{a+b}\big(bx[n]+ay[n]+b^2x[n-1]+aby[n-1]\big)\tag{4}$$

Bringing all terms with $y[n]$ to the left side gives

$$y[n]\frac{b}{a+b}=\frac{1}{a+b}\big(bx[n]+b^2x[n-1]+aby[n-1]\big)\tag{5}$$

which finally results in

$$y[n]=x[n]+bx[n-1]+ay[n-1]\tag{6}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still a student and have not learned Z-transform yet and this assignment occurred in my book before introducing the transform. That's why I couldn't use it and needed a sample-domain method.

Comment: Sure thing I marked it.